# ehcache for both spring method-caching and hibernate level 2 cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache

I would like to setup both spring method caching and an hibernate level 2 cache backed up by ehcache:

The hibernate level 2 cache is already configured in spring-context.xml:

```
<!-- hibernate level 2 cache configuration -->
<bean id="hibernateCacheManager"
    class="net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager" 
    factory-bean="hibernateCacheManagerFactory"
    factory-method="createCacheManager"
    destroy-method="shutdown" />
<bean id="hibernateCacheManagerFactory" 
    class="com.project.CustomEhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
```

The cache configuration is read from a custom xml file so that we can customize our needs and test the cached entities easily:

```
public class CustomEhCacheManagerFactoryBean {
    public CacheManager createCacheManager() {
        final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();            
        // read the xml configuration
        //for each node in xml
            final CacheConfiguration cache = new CacheConfiguration();
            // set the properties
            configuration.addCache(cache);
        // end for
        cacheManager = CacheManager.create(configuration);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add spring method caching with another cache manager using annotation this time. I added the following in my spring-context.xml:

```
<!-- suport method caching through annotation -->
<cache:annotation-driven />
<!-- spring method cache configuration -->
<bean id="cacheManager" 
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="springEhcache"/>
</bean>
<bean id="springEhcache" 
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManagerName" value="method-cache" />
</bean>
```

Then I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: loadCaches must not return an empty Collection
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:268)
at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractCacheManager.java:49)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
```

`Q1`: Shouldn't the caches be configured automagically by annotation? did I miss something?

`Q2`: Is it possible to give this bean id `springCacheManager` instead of `cacheManager`? for the moment I get exception: No bean 'cacheManager' found

Thanks

Comment: it seems to me you miss config location property for `springEhcache` bean, that defines list of caches and their configuration

Comment: @hoaz it does a fallback on the ehcache-failsafe.xml and my spring services are annotated with `[at]Cacheable`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: the exception says, that `springEhcache` bean factory returns cache manager with no caches configured. your @Cachable annotation specifies what cache it is going to use, but you should provide cache configuration anyway via standard ehcache.xml

Comment: @hoaz nice, i ended up configuring the cache in our custom xml configuration and providing a CacheManager factory for each CacheManager. Everything works well now! Thanks for the advice.